# Simulate default patternnet with feedforwardnet in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I got very different training efficiency with the following network

```
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);
```

and the following one

```
net = feedforwardnet(hiddenLayerSize, 'trainscg');
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'softmax';
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';
```

on the same data.

I was thinking networks should be the same.

What thing I forgot?

**UPDATE**

The code below demonstrates, that network behavior is uniquely depends on network creation function.

Each type of network was ran two times. This excludes random generator issues or something. Data is the same.

```
hiddenLayerSize = 10;

% pass 1, with patternnet
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);

y = net(x);
performance = perform(net,t,y);

fprintf('pass 1, patternnet, performance: %f\n', performance);
fprintf('num_epochs: %d, stop: %s\n', tr.num_epochs, tr.stop);

% pass 2, with feedforwardnet
net = feedforwardnet(hiddenLayerSize, 'trainscg');
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'softmax';
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);

y = net(x);
performance = perform(net,t,y);

fprintf('pass 2, feedforwardnet, performance: %f\n', performance);
fprintf('num_epochs: %d, stop: %s\n', tr.num_epochs, tr.stop);

% pass 1, with patternnet
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);

y = net(x);
performance = perform(net,t,y);

fprintf('pass 3, patternnet, performance: %f\n', performance);
fprintf('num_epochs: %d, stop: %s\n', tr.num_epochs, tr.stop);

% pass 2, with feedforwardnet
net = feedforwardnet(hiddenLayerSize, 'trainscg');
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'softmax';
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);

y = net(x);
performance = perform(net,t,y);

fprintf('pass 4, feedforwardnet, performance: %f\n', performance);
fprintf('num_epochs: %d, stop: %s\n', tr.num_epochs, tr.stop);
```

Output follows:

```
pass 1, patternnet, performance: 0.116445
num_epochs: 353, stop: Validation stop.
pass 2, feedforwardnet, performance: 0.693561
num_epochs: 260, stop: Validation stop.
pass 3, patternnet, performance: 0.116445
num_epochs: 353, stop: Validation stop.
pass 4, feedforwardnet, performance: 0.693561
num_epochs: 260, stop: Validation stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like those two aren't quite the same:

```
>> net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);
>> net2 = feedforwardnet(hiddenLayerSize,'trainscg');
>> net.outputs{2}.processParams{2}

ans =

    ymin: 0
    ymax: 1

>> net2.outputs{2}.processParams{2}

ans =

    ymin: -1
    ymax: 1
```

The `net.outputs{2}.processFcns{2}` is `mapminmax` so I gather that one of these is re-scaling it's output to match the output range of your real data better.

For future reference, you can do nasty dirty things like compare the interior data structures by casting to struct.  So I did something like

```
n = struct(net); n2 = struct(net2);
for fn=fieldnames(n)';
  if(~isequaln(n.(fn{1}),n2.(fn{1})))
    fprintf('fields %s differ\n', fn{1});
  end
end
```

to help pinpoint the differences.

Answer (score 0):

As usually network not behave each training absolutely the same way. It can depend from three ( I mean I know three ) reasons:

1. Initial initialization of neural network.
2. Normalization of data
3. Scaling of data
   If to speak about (1) the network is initially configured with random weights, in some small range with different signs. For example neuron with 6 inputs can get initial weights like this: 0.1, -0.3, 0.16, -0.23, 0.015, -0.0005. And this can lead to little bit another training result. If to speak about (2) if your normalization is performed poorly then learning algorithm converges to local minima, and can't jump out of it. The same applies to case (3) if your data is in need of scaling, and you didn't make it.

Comment: See my update please. 1-3 can't be a reasons, since the results are reproducing on multiple runs: `patternnet` systematically performs better than (apparently) the same `feedforwardnet`. So the reason is (probably) I initialize `feedforwardnet` differently, The question is: what is the difference.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/patternnet.html.  feedforwardnet is more universal and intended more for approximation functions, while patternnet is more for patterns recognition.

Comment: If your task data is more fitting  for patternnet, then patternnet will perform better, and if your task data is more fitting for feedforwardnet, then feedforwardnet will perform better.

Comment: `patternnet` calls `feedforwardnet` inside and both output `network` object. The question is: what is the actual difference between two ways of creation. I tried to reproduce it by setting appropriate transfer and performance functions, but apparently failed. The question is: what I forgot to do?

Comment: your task is for classification or for approximation?

Comment: The data is for classification, but it doesn't matter. The data is the same for both calls. The goal is to make `feedforwardnet` work the same as `patternnet`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74812/discussion-between-yura-zaletskyy-and-suzan-cioc).

Comment: Tried to comment on your chat but it's not there anymore. I still think it's the weights as @YuraZaletskyy said. I'm getting different performance with random data.
http://pastebin.com/4DBGf6z6

Comment: Here is my random data generation. http://pastebin.com/KmhZM3A8 Same error doesn't mean the weights are the same. Have you checked the weights/biases themselves?

Comment: I think the actual issue is the method that each function initializes the weights differently based on the data. If I'm not mistaken, each of these methods do pre-processing to find good initial weights based on the type of data (pattern vs general). I'm going to hunt for some documentation!

Comment: @SuzanCioc Nvm it looks like `patterned` calls `feedforwardnet` with your parameters. Can you upload the data that you tested with for me to reproduce the issue? I can't seem to reproduce the issue with my random data.